# Is Simon a White Martian?

Tags: dc, young-justice

In the animated television series Young Justice, The Team has several run ins with an enemy telepath named Simon I didn't notice this until it is revealed that Miss Martian is actually a white Martian rather than a Green one and I noticed the physical similarities between Miss Martian and Simon and it got me thinking.

**Is Simon a white Martian? And if so then why doesn't he use other Martian powers such as Shapeshifting, Telekinesis, Density Shifting, and Extreme Transparency?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Psimon is not a Martian.**

Psimon is a human, born in United States of America. [He got his powers from Trigon, a demon.](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Simon_Jones_%28New_Earth%29#Origin)

His powers are:

- Psychokinesis
- Telekinesis
- Telepathy

And he's also really smart. As impressive as that is, he's only human.

His origin story:
[image]
From New Teen Titans volume 1, Issue 3, from year 1981.

Comment: Really? Wow I thought that with his ultra pale skin and exposed brain that he was a white Martian for sure.

Comment: @TheMandolorian he's definitely human. Sure, you can see the effects of daemonic influence on him, but still human.